# Is it possible to use ebtables to filter traffic by MAC-addresses on simple ethernet interface, without bridging?

Tags: linux, firewall, ethernet

I have a linux machine (my workstation). From there I can ping other local machines, let's say 192.168.1.22. Let's say I want to prohibit communication with 192.168.1.22 by it's MAC address. I'm trying a simple rule:

```
ebtables -I INPUT -s 00:24:1d:c9:0a:27 -j DROP
```

But still I can ping that host. Is ebtables limited to filtering traffic only on bridge interfaces?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, ebtables only acts on frames traversing bridge interfaces. You can, however, do a nice layering violation and use the -m mac --mac-source iptables option.

Whenever I'm doing anything at all complex with netfilter I keep this diagram close to hand:
http://jengelh.medozas.de/images/nf-packet-flow.png

Answer (score 4):

Thor, what you suggest is correct and is working. I justed tested it.

You may need to update the routes by replacing bridged interfaces with the bridge interface itself, to make sure you're not bypassing the bridge.

```
ip route del 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1
```